# Alert primary key insert

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

How to create a primary key alerts when the data input together with CodeIgniter?
example if I insert 001 but in the database already exists 001 subsequently appeared alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Model you can run an SQL query to see if the primary key is already present. If it is, then you can simply return an error code to the Controller, which should handle things from there (by sending an error message to the View).

Model

```
function checkPrimaryKey($primary_key){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE primary_key = '$primary_key'";
    /* Replace table_name And primary_key With Actual Table Name And Column Name */
    $query=$this->db->query($sql);
    if($query->num_rows() == 1){
        return -1; //Key already exists
    }
    else{
        return 0;  //Key does not exist
    }
}
```

Controller

```
function checkPrimaryKey($primary_key){
    $this->load->model('Model_name');
    if($this->Model_name->checkPrimaryKey($primary_key)==-1){
        //Appropriate Error Message
    }
    else {
        //Call Some Model Function to Insert The Data And/Or Display Appropriate Success Message
    }
}
```

Comment: can you write script example